# How to change the styling of an element using JS when it has no class or ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html file (converted from docx) and it does not have any class names or ids. How can I style it using JS? For example, if I need to change the color of the heading for the below file HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is the heading</h1>
    <p>Hello, my name is xyz and this is a para</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I tried, but `document.getElementByTagName()` does not return the element like `document.getElementById()`

```
console.log('hello world');
Heading = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
console.log(Heading);
Heading.style.color = 'blue';
```

Edit:
I tried the below code, but it returns undefined

```
console.log('hello world');
Heading = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
console.log(Heading);
Heading.style.color = 'blue';
```

[image]

Comment: Can you not give it an ID? You could select it via element type, child of and index, but using ID would be less error prone.

Comment: And the issue in your code is that [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName) returns an array, but you're using is as if it were a single element. Add `[0]` and it should work :)

Comment: I am not sure how to add id to it as I am converting it from docx to HTML file to edit it.. Later I will convert it back to docx.. Is there an easier method?

Comment: Adding `[0]` returns undefined..

Comment: Are you adding it in the correct place? Likely a typo, here's [a working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71973444/979052) for you.

Comment: why don't you use the document.querySelector('h1')?

Comment: Is your script running before your html is loaded?

Comment: querySelector returns none...

Comment: How do I verify? @user1599011

Comment: The error you describe is a main symptom. The script is included in the head before the body loads. If the JS isn't in a function, it's running when the JS file loads, before the html. Put it in a function and call it after the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your code like this. you imported the script before html.
There are two solutions. first you have to import script after html or use

```
window.addEventListener
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const heading = document.querySelector('h1');
  heading.style.color = 'blue';
});
```

```html
<h1>This is the heading</h1>
<p>Hello, my name is xyz and this is a para</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `document.querySelector()` as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is the heading</h1>
    <p>Hello, my name is xyz and this is a para</p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const header = document.querySelector('h1');
    console.log(header);
    header.style.color = 'blue';
</script>
</html>
```

One other thing to note is - we need to wait for the page to load, otherwise your javascript code runs first and returns undefined.

You can ensure javascript to run after page load using any of the below ways -

1. Add an event listener – `document.addEventListener("load", FUNCTION);`
2. Add onload to the body tag – `<body onload="FUNCTION()">`
3. Defer the script – `<script src="SCRIPT.js" defer>`
4. Lastly, place the script at the very bottom of the page – Although this is not quite “after page load”.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName) returns an array, but you're using is as if it were a single element.

Try this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const heading = document.querySelector('h1');
  heading.style.color = 'blue';
});
```

```html
<h1>This is the heading</h1>
<p>Hello, my name is xyz and this is a para</p>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I copy pasted the code and it still returns undefined...

Comment: Are you sure that you have a `h1` element on your page? Try opening the console, running `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('h1'));` what do you see?